# Django: Admin Panel - Select an existing image from any folder without creating duplicates

Tags: django

I'm looking for a way to use images that are already in the media folder.

```
models.ImageField(upload_to = "madia/images/pages" verbose_name=('img'))
```

Selecting images for a post in the admin panel creates a duplicate of an existing image.

if i remove upload_to, the selected image is duplicated in media.

Is there a field that allows you to select an existing image from any folder on the server, without being tied to a specific folder - without duplicating images?

Answer (score 0):

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.queryset.get(id=kwargs['pk']).employee_image
    if queryset:
        try:
            if request.data['employee_image'] is not None:
                queryset.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            pass
    serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=True)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_update(serializer)

    if getattr(instance, '_prefetched_objects_cache', None):
        instance._prefetched_objects_cache = {}

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

this update method will update your existing image to upload image and delete previous one where all images are stored.

**Note**:
you can implement it as like in Django, it's implemented in DRF